# use HTTP.get to get data posted via HTTP.post in meteor

Tags: web-services, meteor, service, http-get, httplistener

I have built an app using meteorjs. I need some data from a third party. They would send me the data via HTTP.POST method.

I need listen on my app to lookout for http.post requests. If I encounter such request, I need to send an acknowledgement saying the request was received and then I need to extract the data sent.

I am using the below code but the output is not as expected.

Using picker package,

```
var postData = {
"channelName" : "Number Theory1",
"startDate" : "2017-07-22T06:29:35.681Z",
"endDate" : "2017-08-22T06:29:35.681Z"
}
HTTP.call('POST', 'http://localhost:3000', {
   data: postData 
 }, (error, result) => {
 if (error) {
   console.log('we are getting this error:' + error);
 } else {
    console.log('POstres : ' + result);
 }
 }); 
function extractProcessData(data){
   console.log('function called! : ' + data);
}
function confirmDataReceived(data) {
  HTTP.get('http://localhost:3000', function(err, res){
  // confirmation error
  if(err){
    console.log('error ' + err);
  }
  // confirmation success and process data
  else{
    console.log('data : ' + data + res)
    extractProcessData(data) //call function to process data
  }
});
}
var postRoutes = Picker.filter(Meteor.bindEnvironment(function(req, res) {
 if (req.method == "POST"){
   console.log('req : ' + req.method + " " + req.body)
   confirmDataReceived(req.body);
 }
 return true;
 // return req.method == "POST";
}));;;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: why are you doing Session.set('flag'... instead of calling a function and wrapping your if(Session.get.. into a function. You need to be aware that the if(Session... test at the moment is only run once when the server is started. Further calls to modify the session are not executing this statements again.

Comment: okay. So i need to take the if(session.get()) part and make into a function. then call that function in where session.set is called, right? another doubt i had was dont i need a httplistener to detect http.post requests?

Comment: i provided an answer with the steps i think are necessary. You do not need a httplistener, that is the Picker router for you. You could also run your own listener, but if you already have routing in place (like Picker) than there is no need, because all requests are running through Picker

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a middle ware library. I have used 2 in the past.

**Picker** is the simplest to implement and use something as simple as

```
Picker.route('/post/:_id', function(params, req, res, next) {
  var post = Posts.findOne(params._id);
  res.end(post.content);
});
```

https://github.com/meteorhacks/picker

Then there is more robust solutions, **Restivus**, that will handle authentication and advanced stream management (file upload chunking as an example) etc but requires more work to get started.

https://github.com/kahmali/meteor-restivus

Answer (score 2):

As far as i understand your requirement the process should work like the following

1. you receive a post request from a third party
2. you need to confirm via a get request to the third party

In order to do so i believe you defined a specific url on your server to act as endpoint, and to properly filter those post requests you are using the Picker router (i am not very familiar with this one)

For the first part (the post request) i would suggest the following:

```
var postRoutes = Picker.filter(function(req, res) {
   // here you could be a bit more specific in which
   // post request you are looking for, e.g. check the req.url
   if (req.method == "POST") {
      confirmDataReceived(req.body);
   }
   return true;
});
```

Then we can move on to the second part and send the confirmation to the third party and use the provided data to call your defined function to process it.

```
function confirmDataReceived(data) {
  // send the confirmation
  HTTP.get('http://122.160.157.105:3000', function(err, res){
    // confirmation error
    if(err){
        console.log('error ' + err);
    }
    // confirmation success and process data
    else
        fname(data) //call function
    });
}
```

Comment: can you describe more what is happening and what is going on otherwise it is difficult to guide you. I do not know what you need the first HTTP.call('POST' for this is making a post request from your server to somewhere else if this is required i did not understand what your initial request was. do you have any documentation on the api you are trying to use?